# placeholder functions in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

```
# python 2.7.10
# sympy 0.7.6
import sympy as sym
a, b, c, x = sym.symbols('a b c x')
F = sym.symbols('F', cls=sym.Function)
```

Suppose we have an expression:

```
expr = F(a - b) - F(b**2 - c)
```

Is there a way to replace the unknown function `F` with a known function `F(x) = x**0.5 + 1`? For example:

```
result = expr.subs(F(_), _**0.5 + 1)
```

Which would result in:

```
(a - b)**0.5 - (b**2 - c)**0.5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [1]: import sympy as sm
In [2]: a, b, c, x = sm.symbols('a b c x')
In [3]: F = sm.symbols('F', cls=sm.Function)
In [4]: expr = F(a - b) - F(b**2 - c)
```

You can use SymPy's [Lambda](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html?highlight=lambda#sympy.core.function.Lambda) function to define a custom function.

```
In [5]: G = sm.Lambda(x, sqrt(x) + 1)
In [6]: expr.subs(F, G)
Out[6]: sqrt(a - b) - sqrt(b**2 - c)
```

Comment: Good to know.  I've never used sympy's Lambda function.  I'd be curious to know what the trade-offs are for using a lambda vs. subclassing a function.

Comment: Subclassing can be tedious and require some code. This can cause unexpected errors. Inbuilt functions are well tested and usually play well with other functions. As your comment in the above question, a lot of functions will have to be defined for a complete set of functionality and for the function to play well with the assumptions. So, there is no need to invent something for which there is already a function. @ptb

Comment: Just for for the sake of completeness: @smichr gives a very elegant solution as well, using `sympy.Wild` symbols and `replace`.

Answer (score 2):

`replace` is made for this purpose:

```
>>> import sympy as sym
>>> a, b, c, x = sym.symbols('a b c x')
>>> F = sym.symbols('F', cls=sym.Function)
>>> expr = F(a - b) - F(b**2 - c)
>>> arg=Wild('arg')
>>> expr.replace(F(arg), sqrt(arg) + 1)
sqrt(a - b) - sqrt(b**2 - c)
```

Comment: I did not know the Wild symbol, thanks. It does work with multiple arguments as well, e.g. `expr.replace(F(arg1, arg2), sqrt(arg1) + arg2**2)`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by subclassing `Function` and defining the proper `eval` method (http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/core.html#id50)

```
In [1]: from sympy import Function, sqrt

In [2]: from sympy.abc import x, y, z, a, b, c

In [4]: f = Function('f')

In [5]: expr = f(a-b)+f(b**2-c)

In [6]: expr
Out[6]: f(a - b) + f(b**2 - c)

In [11]: class F(Function):
   ....:     
   ....:     @classmethod
   ....:     def eval(cls, x):
   ....:        return sqrt(x)+1
   ....:    

In [12]: expr.subs(f, F)
Out[12]: sqrt(a - b) + sqrt(b**2 - c) + 2
```

Python's `type` function can be used to shorten the definition of `F`

```
In [13]: G = type('G', (Function, ),
        {'eval' : classmethod(lambda self, x : sqrt(x)+1)})

In [14]: expr.subs(f, G)
Out[14]: sqrt(a - b) + sqrt(b**2 - c) + 2

In [15]:
```

Comment: Very well, so I'll have to dive into subclassing. Do you have any suggestions on a complete list of class methods needed for a proper `sympy.Function` subclass? Anything optional needed for the above case?

Comment: Both the `F` and `G` above are fully functioning 'proper' subclasses.  If you plan on using the assumption system you'll have to define an obscene number of methods but the above should suffice if substitution is your primary goal.  The only other thing you may want is to define `nargs` if you want your function to take multiple arguments.